# sql error on creating a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete

I typed this code into mysql and it gave an error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_vote_topic BEFORE DELETE ON vote_topic
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM vote_option WHERE vote_topic_id = OLD.id;
    DELETE FROM vote_option_votes WHERE vote_topic_id = OLD.id;
  END;
```

the error was:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a delimiter

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER delete_vote_topic BEFORE DELETE ON vote_topic 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
     DELETE FROM vote_option 
     WHERE vote_topic_id = OLD.id; 
     DELETE FROM vote_option_votes 
     WHERE vote_topic_id = OLD.id; 
END;

|
```